# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Comment>'. Why can't Dart infer this type? How do I fix this?

Tags: dart

I have nested comments. In order to fetch them from JSON, I have the following `fromJson()` function:

```
Comment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        ...
        children = json['children'] != null
            ? json['children'].map((c) => Comment.fromJson(c)).toList()
            : null,
        ...
```

This checks if the current comment has any children comments, and if so, recursively parses them from JSON into a Comment. However when I run this, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(214)]
Dart Unhandled Exception: 
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Comment>'
stack trace: #0      new Comment.fromJson (package:app/models/comment.dart:43:18)
```

Which points to the line where I assign children with `children = json...`. I'm new to dart, but I don't understand how mapping over a list, and returning a Comment doesn't let Dart infer the type of the list. How do I fix this? Adding `as List<Comment>` after `toList()` didn't work. If I add `as Comment` after `Comment.fromJson(c)`, I get `unnecessary cast`.

Comment: Are you calling  `Comment.fromJson()` from inside `Comment.fromJson()`? Is it a recurrssive call?

Comment: @Sisir Correct, this `Comment.fromJson()` is inside my `class Comment{}`

Comment: That's ok. But are you calling the method from inside the same method? Or is it a typo error.

Comment: @Sisir Yes, from inside the same method. It's recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart can't infer anything from `json['children'].map(...).toList()` because `json['children']` is of type `dynamic`, and therefore it doesn't know what the `.map` call is going to resolve to at runtime.

At runtime, since `.map` is called without an explicit type, it ends up being a call to `.map<dynamic>(...)`, and then `.toList()` returns `List<dynamic>`.

Try either:

- Explicitly using `.map<Comment>(...)`.
- Casting `json['children']`: `(json['children'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>).map(...)`.  It'd probably be a good idea to validate this anyway.

Comment: Thank you. `.map<Comment>(...)` fixed it for me.